# regular expression to match package in exported function

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to create a function to extract package names from my scripts. So far I have been able to extract all packages that are loaded using `library` or `require`. I also noticed that sometimes I have used functions using the `::` operator. I have the following for those cases but is not working:

```
a <- c(
  "ggplot2::aes()",
  "                      digest::digest(data))",
  "  data <- dplyr::rbind_all(data)"
)
gsub('^(.+)::(.+)', '\\1', a)
```

In this example; I would like to get `ggplot2, digest and dplyr` back as a vector.

Comment: so your output should give you ggplot2, digest and dplyr as answer?

Comment: `'^(.+)::(.+)'` The first capture group here matches any characters from the beginning of the line up to the last `::` in the string. That regular expression is working as I'd expect it to work.  What are the conditions for a match?

Answer (score 1):

For the extraction of package names from string, [regmatches](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regmatches.html), [regexec](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) functions are used.

**step1**: Extract terms before `::`

```
s1 <- regmatches(a, regexec("^.*?::",a))
> s1
[[1]]
[1] "ggplot2::"

[[2]]
[1] "                      digest::"

[[3]]
[1] "  data <- dplyr::"
```

**Explanation** :

```
    ^ asserts position at start of a line
    .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
    *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
    :: matches the characters :: literally (case sensitive)
```

**step2**: Replace `::`, whitespaces and term before `<-`,

```
s2 <- gsub(".*(<-)|::| ","",s1)
> s2
[1] "ggplot2" "digest"  "dplyr"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract`

```
out <- str_extract("data <- dplyr::rbind_all(data)", regex("[a-zA-Z]+::"))
> substr(out, 1, (nchar(out)-2))
[1] "dplyr" 

> out <- str_extract("digest::digest(data))", regex("[a-zA-Z]+::"))
> substr(out, 1, (nchar(out)-2))
[1] "digest"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
## Your data:
a <- c("ggplot2::aes()",
        "   data.table::dcast(data, time ~ variable, fun = mean)",
        "  data <- dplyr::rbind_all(data)")

## Extract string that consists of letters, numbers or a dot
## and has at least two characters (= package naming conventions),
## and that is followed by "::"
stringr::str_extract(a, "[[:alnum:].]{2,}(?=::)")
# [1] "ggplot2"    "data.table" "dplyr"
```